# Shortcut To Full Screen App In Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, vmware-fusion, fullscreen

I postponed getting OSX Lion for as long as I possibly could.  Now that I have it, I'm having lots of difficulties getting it to perform how I want.

On Snow Leopard my typical setup for working was 4 spaces.  I'd keep a Windows VM open on Space #4 full-screened, a Linux open on space #3, and I'd do other stuff on spaces #1 and #2.  My keyboard shortcut allowed me to switch between my Windows work (Command + 4) to my Linux work (Command + 3) very quickly, and without the need for my hands to leave the keyboard (or effectively to even quit typing).  Productivity was good.

I see that on Lion a full-screened VM (and yes, they need to be full screened, Fusion's Unity won't cut it for what I need to do) is its own separate Desktop.  I have set up 4 desktops and made my keyboard shortcuts to move between them Command + # just as before.  But how do I get my full-screened VM to be one of those already existing desktops?  Or, rather, how do I make a short-cut for the full-screened app?

Comment: So to clarify, you don't like the dynamic allocation and reordering of desktops whenever you move an app to full screen or switch between them using `Cmd-Tab`, and want one shortcut to always mean "the Linux desktop" instead of "screen 4"?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I want one shortcut to always mean "the Linux desktop" instead of "go to dashboard and click the Linux desktop" or "cycle through the desktops and locate the one that's the Linux desktop".

Comment: Spaces does not exist for AppleScript (for example, `tell application "System Events" to tell process "Mail" to windows` should list open Mail windows — the full screen space does not count!). TotalSpaces also ignores full screen application spaces. I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Does your VM software have an option to use a custom (or the old) full screen implementation?

Comment: @DanielBeck seems that this is another consequence of Apple's "just works" technology.

Comment: @Lri I don't know if it does?  How would I check?  I'm just using the latest version of VMWare Fusion.

Comment: @omghai2u For example WriteRoom, VLC, and MacVim just have a checkbox in the preferences for using custom full screen windows. But I downloaded a trial of VMWare and it didn't seem to have anything like that.

Comment: @Lri Ah yeah, I see that behavior now with VLC.  Seems like it's a VMWare problem, then?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no shortcut to go directly to a full screen app. Someone on [this question on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21370/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-jump-directly-to-a-particular-full-screen-app-in) suggested [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), but I would just use a [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/) trigger.